# Magento 2.3 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, jquery, console

Installed Magento 2.3.1 with sample data there are no js errors on the console. After changing the theme to Ves Need from Venustheme.

http://www.venustheme.com/theme/ves-need/

On hard refresh, the below issue occurs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
```

Can someone please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: can you post complete error log

Comment: Upgraded the jquery-ui from 1.10 to 1.12, now no issues. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated jquery-ui from 1.10 to 1.12 now the version issue has been resolved.

Comment: I'm getting this error as well, could you share the process you used to upgrade jQuery?

Comment: On Magento 2.2, under lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js replace the downloaded jquery-ui codes.

Finally, run the below command from the Magento root directory
`code`
sudo chmod 777 -R var/* pub/* generated/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod 777 -R var/* pub/* generated/*
`code`

Comment: This is one of the worst solutions I have ever seen, after an upgrade - your file will be overridden. This makes project hard to update which is known as big no no.

Comment: @Macas It worked on my end. That's why posted as an answer here.

Comment: Even if it is working, it doesn't mean that it is a right solution.
At least you could inform other users that this is a temporary workaround not a fix.

Comment: I have tried upgrade of jquery-ui and it's works for me .... anyone can try this and if it works upvote it else mention your status in the comment... even it's not a temporary fix for me